# How to send SMS via SMPP using mblox?

Tags: c#, .net, smpp

Is there any open source scripts or resources available to inetegrate mblox using SMPP in .net framework ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need only free then you can see :

- [RoaminSMPP](http://ostatic.org/roaminsmpp)
- [EasySMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easysmpp/)
- Also look for DevShock

Comment: Thanks, I have to implement for Premium Customers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind paying for a good solution you can check out:

- [Mobile Messaging Toolkit](http://www.activexperts.com/mobile-messaging-component/)
- [SMS Messaging Server](http://www.activexperts.com/sms-messaging-server/)

Both provide excellent support for SMPP in C#.